# Is this map injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. Consider the linear map 
$$
\Psi : W_2^* \otimes W_1 \to \text{Hom}(W_2,W_1)
$$
such that for $\phi \in W_2^*$ and $u \in W_1$,
$$
\Psi(\phi \otimes u)(v) = \phi(v)u
$$
where $\text{Hom}$ is the space of linear maps between the vector spaces (assume that this map exists and is unique). The book claims this map is invertible. I tried showing injectivity and that seems to not be true. For example if $\phi =0$ then $v$ is mapped to $0$ irrespective of $u$, and vice versa. Am I missing something? This is from Appendix D of the book "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations" by Brian Hall.

Comment: What you are missing is that the representation $\sum \phi_i\otimes u_i$ of elements of the tensor product is not unique. You gave an example for this.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you I think I understand. So should this mean that as long as I show that at least one of $\phi$ or $u$ are zero (which I have done but did not write here), then that is sufficient?

Comment: There are more reasons that $\sum \phi_i\otimes u_i$ can be $0$.

Comment: @Jochen But I mean if one of $\phi$  or $u$ are zero then it is zero? So showing that the $\phi(v) u= 0$ for all $v$ implies $\phi$ or $u$ are zero which implies that $\phi \otimes u$ is zero. I guess I have to consider linear combinations of $\phi \otimes u$ as well?

Comment: Yes, indeed you have to consider linear combinations. *The* linear map $\Psi$ such that $\Psi(\phi\otimes u)(v)=\phi(v)u$ has to be extended to the linear span of the elementary tensors. Show first that $\Psi(\sum \phi_i\otimes u_i)$ defined by $v\mapsto \sum \phi(v)u_i$ is a well-defined linear map from the tensor product to Hom$(W_2,W_1)$.